# Excel VBA - Why is the data overwriting same row?

Tags: vba, excel

I am running this Sub and it is working but the data scraped is getting written to the second row and each instance is overwriting the last. I can't see where my script is wrong. Please help me understand:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim ele As Object
Dim objIE As Object
Dim RowCount As Double
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myjobtype As String
Dim myzip As String
Dim what
Dim zipcode

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Title"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Company"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Location"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Description"

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myjobtype = InputBox("Enter type of job eg. sales, administration")
myzip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.jobs.com/"

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
what.Item(0).Value = myjobtype
Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("where")
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myzip

.document.forms(0).submit

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
    Select Case ele.classname
        Case "cardview"
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Case "jobTitle"
            sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "company"
            sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "location"
            sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "preview"
            sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
    End Select
Next ele
End With
Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RowCount = RowCount + 1
> ```

Should be moved to outside the `Select Case`, just after the `For Each`.

```
For Each ele In .document.all
   RowCount = RowCount + 1 '<------------------------------- Here
     Select Case ele.classname
       Case "cardview"
       ...
```

This will increment a row for each element, but you will have blank rows for elements not matching any case. If you dont want those empty rows, you can simply decrement again the `RowCount` in the `Case Else`. But a better solution is to simplilfy your `Select` statement, since the same action is undertaken for all the cases:

```
For Each ele In .document.all
  Select Case ele.classname
    Case "cardview", "jobTitle", "company", "location", "preview"
      RowCount = RowCount + 1
      sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
  End Select
Next ele
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, unfortunately moving RowCount outside the Select Case didn't help.

I then replaced the select statement with your suggestion but it put everything into column D. 

How should it increment the column in the same way I increment the Row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why

```
Case "cardview"

RowCount = RowCount + 1
```

is not executed.

But when I moved

```
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
```

below    `Case "jobTitle"`

it then finally worked.